# Unicode literals in string Python 2.7

Tags: python, character-encoding

I run Python Version: 2.7.12 |Anaconda 4.1.1 (64-bit)| (default, Jun 29 2016, 11:07:13) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on Windows 7 64

The problem is the following:

The code below:

```
c = u'\u0022\u03bd'
print c.encode('utf-8')
```

returns `"ν`

Now, I have `\u0022\u03bd` in a notepad file saved with utf-8 encoding say "fl".
The code below

```
with open(fl, 'r') as f:
    cont = f.read()
print cont
cont = unicode(cont, encoding='utf-8')
print cont.encode('utf-8')
```

returns

```
\u0022\u03bd
\u0022\u03bd
```

How can I convert `cont` to `"ν` ?

Comment: You have it. It's just displayed differently.

Comment: So how can I display it the same way

Comment: Do you mean the file contains a literal sequence of backslash, `u`, `0`, `0` etc?

Comment: Yes, the content of the file is \u0022\u03bd